# My F3 button changes my volume instead of doing what it should

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

Every time I press <kbd>F3</kbd> it changes my volume instead of opening the debug overlay. Is there a way I can fix this in settings?

I use the latest version of Minecraft.

Comment: By chance, does your keyboard have an "Fn" Key on the bottom right or bottom left?  F3 still works the same, but this sounds more like your PC as Fn-Lock enabled. (Which turns off Function keys (F1,F2, F3) and replaces it with shortcuts that the computer manufacture usually sets up.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, or that the key was remapped in Minecraft or in Windows. More likely it's the Fn issue since it's changing volume.

Answer (score 19):

If you are playing on a laptop, see if you have a "Fn" key on the keyboard. Mostly likely what has happened is that your computer is configured to require the Fn (function) key to be pressed in order to send F1-F12 keystrokes, instead of the "media" keys like volume up, volume down, screen brightness, etc. This can usually be changed in the BIOS or in Windows itself, depending on the configuration.  This is what the Fn key may look like:

[image: Fn key from a laptop keyboard]

If that doesn't fix your issue, then check Minecraft keymaps and keymappings in Windows and/or your computer's BIOS to see if they can be toggled or changed.

Comment: Thats one horrible Keyboard-Layout I can imagine. Who would replace the Windows-Button with Fn o.O

Comment: @Gigala The Devil.  and pre-Vista laptops I have to assume.

Comment: @NBN-Alex Why pre-Vista? The Windows key has been around since Windows 95; making it 20 years since it was a good idea to put Fn between Ctrl and Alt!

Comment: The Fn key doesn't relate to versions of Windows. It relates to laptop designers realizing they can save a row of keys by combining function keys with the other "media keys" that people came to expect and love on laptop keyboards. That's also a photo I got from wikipedia and could be very old too, I have no idea.

Comment: @IMSoP It's been around for a while, but from personal antidote, It seemed like some OEMs would replace the windows key with an Fn key on short keyboards for laptops. (due to a lack of space)  This is 100% true of course and just an observation from really long ago in comparison. :s

Comment: @NBN-Alex Yeah, I get all that; just wasn't sure what Windows Vista had to do with it, since it seems just as likely for a laptop to use or not use a non-standard layout any time in the last 20 years.

Comment: damnit, can't edit the last comment, meant to say "100% not true" in my observation

Comment: @Gigala I have a relatively high-end gaming laptop, and they purposefully moved the Windows Key to the right of the spacebar to prevent accidental presses during games. While it's more of a pain when I do actually need it, it has helped with me accidentally hitting and causing who-knows-what to happen.

Answer (score 8):

If this is a regular keyboard, not a laptop, look for an "F Lock" button:

[image: F Lock]

When F lock is on, your function keys will work as function keys.  Many newer keyboards have them default to multimedia or other hotkeys instead of their normal function.

Comment: Microsoft keyboards? Ewwww ;)

Comment: @TimS. Just an example.  Most logitech keyboards have it too.

Comment: @TimS. - MS keyboards are amazing. Hate it or love it, MS makes great hardware. Unfortunately, they often botch the software.

Comment: @TimS. Hey now, I love my Natural Ergonomic 4000. It may not be the best gaming keyboard, but it can still do gaming. And it's really comfortable to use.

Comment: @jab me too.  I buy extras when they go on sale for the sad day when they stop making them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my HP laptop. I had to boot up the computer, pressing the appropriate key during boot (I had to look up the laptop model online to figure it out) to get me into the BIOS menu system, then I had to poke around to figure out how to change the default meaning of the function keys from being "media" keys to being "function" keys. This isn't particularly difficult, just time-consuming and frustrating. An F-lock key as described by @Grant would have made this much simpler. Are you listening, HP? (Probably not. The HP of today seems more interested in repeating their past mistakes (HP cell phone, anyone?) instead of doing what they do well - which since the days of Carly Fiorina, the Compaq takeover, and the departure from the test equipment business seems to be "nothing").

Feh...